# O365 SharePoint blocked users

Tags: azure, sharepoint, migration, office365

I am trying to migrate old documents from onprem to SPO. All users have been synced via Azure AD, but employees that no longer work here, have been Blocked (Active users - but blocked).

Now it's a business requirement that the history for these documents are preserved, and therefore I need to add some of these blocked users as part of metadata is needed. It's not possible to do it via the peoplepicker in the UI (blocked users can't be found), and neither via CSOM. Is there any workaround for this?

```
var user = context.Web.EnsureUser(value); // The specified user xx@yy.com could not be found
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if this has been asked on [SharePoint SE](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/)?